# How to be productive in a old large complex mentenance project

Tags: c#, performance, architecture

I am a dot net developer. I recently joined a team where the application is a legacy application build over 4+ years. Now the expectation from my manager is that - 
1. I should be more productive cleaning, refactoring old code improving performance problems.

But the thing is - Product Release is very near now and performance is very slow. Also as i joined newly in the team, when i see some complex UN-necessary logic, but i feel fear to change it because it should not break existing functionality or the patch fix made.

Please suggest the best practices to follow in order to tackle such scenario and being more productive 
to exceed the expectations.

- Even though i feel i am technically sound enough but i am not able to utilize
  So one my well wisher suggested me to improve on "Code-Readability". Any similar suggestion or experiences will help me

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you search for appropriate topics on http://programmers.stackexchange.com where this would be on-topic, contrary to here.

Comment: I suggest you search for... another job

Comment: _"I should be more productive cleaning, refactoring old code improving performance problems."_ - then start writing unit tests, because changing code without tests is ... well, just changing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only suggestion I have is where possible ensure you have unit tests that cover the current functionality - then you are free to improve functions/performance without fear of breaking existing functionality.  The investment spent in getting good code coverage often pays dividends when the need to refactor/improve performance arises.

As for readability - ensuring that the code is broken down into coherent functions rather than monolithic code blocks always helps...